# Обновление Include

Tags: php, javascript

Доброго времени суток
имеется выпадающий список с наполнением в виде инклюда (в котором находится запрос к базе)

```
 <select id="ttt">
     <option class="optval" value=""></option>
     <?php include_once("mh/formhelp.php");  ?>
 </select>
```

нужно обновлять информацию о запросе  и соответственно сам выпадающий список при добавлении записи в базу . но что то я туплю как это провернуть.. просьба подсказать помочь, кинуть тапком в правильную сторону

Comment: так что-ли ?

     foreach($options as $key=>$option) {echo  "<option class=\"optval\" value=\"$key\">$option</option>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из вопроса не понятно о каком запросе речь и чем его можно обновлять.

Допустим, что вы выкачиваете всё, что было в базе в виде запроса. Тогда вы будете обновлять option из того, что у вас из базы пришло, а не обновлять то, что из базы пришло.

Не забывайте, что при запросе в базу вы на выходе получаете не массив fetch_assoc и подобные вам в помощь. Что дальше делать уже описал eicto.

Comment: для полноты вопроса код запроса 

$query = "SELECT type FROM `towar` GROUP BY type";
$res = mysql_query($query) or die ("Не могу подключиться к базе1111.");

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $res, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ) {
    $tmp.= '<option class="optval" value="' . $row [ 'type' ] . '">' . $row [ 'type' ] . "</option>";
}

echo $tmp;


из базы выкачиваю типы.. и вопрос в том что на момент открытия страницы, я получаю из базы самые свежие сведения, но при добавлении нового в базу этот список само сабой устаревает, и меня интерисует способ обновить его (повторить sql запрос из инклуда)